# Determining whether a file is linked to a project or not

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I'm writing a project documenter and I write out the full file path of each compiled file. This is for the VB.NET language so .proj files are written in xml.

Any file that is linked to the project exists on the same drive so at least one of the directory levels are the same for all files. I currently have it set up to put the project directory path on files which exist inside the project since it only shows the name of the file and the residing directory it lives in if its in a directory inside the project. For files outside (linked in) to the project I initially saw their files paths were "..\..\..\dir\filename". So I set it up to take off all the "..\" and put the necessary directories in front of it and all that worked fine. Now for this one .proj file some of the linked in files have their full file path with no "..\".

How can I properly distinguish these three possible inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.IO.Path.IsRooted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.ispathrooted(v=vs.110).aspx) will tell you whether a path is rooted, i.e. is a full path, or not. If the path is not rooted it is a relative path. You can use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to resolve the full path from a relative path.

Comment: Works just as expected. Thank you!